# Exported Primefaces Datatable isn't able to show all data

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

I have a dynamic table in primefaces 10 RC1, looking like this:

```html
<ui:define name="main">
  <h:form id="searchform">
    <p:tabView id="searchtab" activeIndex="#{searchHandler.activeTab}" widgetVar="searchtab" dynamic="true">
      <p:tab id="atcSearchTab" title="Suche">
        <h4>Systeme</h4>
        <p:selectManyCheckbox id="systems" value="#{searchHandler.selectedRefSystems}" layout="grid" columns="2" styleClass="grid-checkbox">
          <f:selectItems value="#{searchHandler.refSystems}" var="refSystem" itemLabel="#{refSystem.displayName()}" itemValue="#{refSystem}"/>
        </p:selectManyCheckbox>
        
        <h4>Suchfeld</h4>
        <p:selectOneMenu id="searchfield" value="#{searchHandler.searchfield}">
          <f:selectItems value="#{searchHandler.selectableSearchfields}"/>
        </p:selectOneMenu>
            
        <h4>Suchbegriffe</h4>
        <p:inputTextarea value="#{searchHandler.searchValueBox}" rows="8" cols="30" autoResize="false"
          placeholder="Bitte hier die gesuchten Systeme, mit Absatz oder Semikolon trennen"/>
        <h4>Suchen</h4>
        <p:commandButton id="searchButton" value="Suche starten" icon="pi pi-search" actionListener="#{searchHandler.search}"/>
      </p:tab>
      <p:tab id="atcResultTab" title="Ergebnis">
        <p:panel id="resultTablePanel" rendered="true">
          <p:toolbar>
            <p:toolbarGroup align="right">
              <p:commandButton value="Export" icon="pi pi-upload" styleClass="ui-button-help" ajax="false">
                <p:dataExporter type="csv" target="atcSearchResults" fileName="search"/>
              </p:commandButton>
            </p:toolbarGroup>
          </p:toolbar>
          <p:dataTable id="atcSearchResults" var="result" value="#{searchHandler.searchResult.searchResults}"
                            allowUnsorting="true" sortMode="single">
                        <p:column headerText="#{searchHandler.searchResult.searchField}">
              <h:outputText value="#{result.getValue(searchHandler.searchResult.searchField)}" />
            </p:column>
                        <p:column headerText="System">
              <h:outputText value="#{result.refSystem}" />
            </p:column>
            <p:columns value="#{searchHandler.searchResult.outputOrder}" var="order" headerText="#{order.header}" 
              field="getValue(order.value)" filterable="false" sortable="false"/>
          </p:dataTable>
        </p:panel>
      </p:tab>
    </p:tabView>
    <p:blockUI block="searchtab" trigger="searchform:searchtab:searchButton" style="float:right;">
      <p:graphicImage value="../resources/images/loader.gif" />
    </p:blockUI>
  </h:form>
</ui:define>
```

I've tried exporting it with the buildIn export function but then my csv-file has only one line looking like `"";"System"` I think that's the showcase of the empty table. My bean class looks like this:

```java
package main.java.handler;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped;
import javax.inject.Named;

import org.primefaces.PrimeFaces;
import org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTable;
import org.primefaces.component.export.Exporter;
import org.primefaces.model.SortMeta;
import org.primefaces.model.SortOrder;

import main.java.atc.controller.TextExporter;
import main.java.atc.definitions.ReferenceSystem;
import main.java.atc.definitions.SearchResult;
import main.java.atc.definitions.SearchResultElement;
import main.java.atc.interfaces.SearchInterface;
import main.java.caches.servercache.ServerCache;
import main.java.refSystems.ActiveConnectors;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@Named("searchHandler")
@SessionScoped
public class SearchHandler  implements Serializable {

    private static final String SPLITTING_REGEX= ";|\\s|\\n";
 
    private List<ReferenceSystem> refSystems;
    private ReferenceSystem[] selectedRefSystems;
    
    private List<String> selectableSearchfields;
    private String searchfield;
    private SortMeta sortBy;
    
    private String searchValueBox;
    
    private SearchResult searchResult;
    private int activeTab = 0;
    private Exporter<DataTable> csvExporter;
    
    @PostConstruct
    private void initHandler() {
        setSortBy(new SortMeta());
        setSearchResult(new SearchResult());
        makeRefSys();
        makeSelectableSearchfields();
        csvExporter = new TextExporter();
    }

    private void makeRefSys() {
        refSystems = new ArrayList<>();
        for(ReferenceSystem r : ActiveConnectors.getActiveRefSys()) {
            refSystems.add(r);
        }
        selectedRefSystems = ReferenceSystem.values();
    }
    
    private void makeSelectableSearchfields() {
        selectableSearchfields = ServerCache.getCache().getSysConf().getSearchableItems();
    }

    public void search() throws Exception {
        searchResult = new SearchResult();
        
        List<SearchResultElement> elementList = new ArrayList<>();

        Map<String,String> valueMap = new HashMap<>();
        valueMap.put("Hostname", "V100SPWCK12121N");
        valueMap.put("STATUS", "PRODUKTIV");
        valueMap.put("SerNr", "123456QWER");
        elementList.add(new SearchResultElement("V100SPWCK12121N", ReferenceSystem.PROIPS, valueMap));
        valueMap = new HashMap<>();
        valueMap.put("Hostname", "V100SPWCK12121N");
        valueMap.put("STATUS", "LAGERHALTIG");
        valueMap.put("SerNr", "123456QWER");
        elementList.add(new SearchResultElement("V100SPWCK12121N", ReferenceSystem.COMMAND, valueMap));
        searchResult.setSearchResults(elementList);
        searchResult.setSearchValue("Hostname");
        searchResult.setSearched(true);
        sortBy = SortMeta.builder()
                .field(searchfield)
                .order(SortOrder.ASCENDING)
                .build();
        activeTab = 1;
        PrimeFaces.current().ajax().update("searchform:searchtab");
    }
    
    private List<String> makeValueList(String searchInput) {
        List<String> splittedInput = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(searchInput.split(SPLITTING_REGEX)));
        splittedInput.remove("");
        return splittedInput; 
    }

    public ReferenceSystem[] getSelectedRefSystems() { return selectedRefSystems; }
    public List<ReferenceSystem> getRefSystems() { return refSystems; }
    public String getSearchfield() { return searchfield; }
    public List<String> getSelectableSearchfields() { return selectableSearchfields; }
    public String getSearchValueBox() { return searchValueBox; }
    public SearchResult getSearchResult() { return searchResult; }
    public int getActiveTab() { return activeTab; }
    public SortMeta getSortBy() { return sortBy; }
    public Exporter<DataTable> getCsvExporter() { return csvExporter; }

    public void setSelectedRefSystems(ReferenceSystem[] selectedRefSystems) { this.selectedRefSystems = selectedRefSystems; }
    public void setRefSystems(List<ReferenceSystem> refSystems) { this.refSystems = refSystems; }
    public void setSearchfield(String searchfield) { this.searchfield = searchfield; }
    public void setSelectableSearchfields(List<String> selectableSearchfields) { this.selectableSearchfields = selectableSearchfields; }
    public void setSearchValueBox(String searchValueBox) { this.searchValueBox = searchValueBox; }
    public void setSearchResult(SearchResult searchResult) { this.searchResult = searchResult; }
    public void setActiveTab(int activeTab) { this.activeTab = activeTab; }
    public void setSortBy(SortMeta sortMeta) { this.sortBy = sortMeta; }
    public void setCsvExporter(Exporter<DataTable> csvExporter) { this.csvExporter = csvExporter; }

 }
```

For Reproduction here the two big additional Classes. The missing restare all ENUMs.

```java
public class SearchResult {

    private String searchField;
    private boolean searched;
    private List<OutputOrder> outputOrder;
    private List<SearchResultElement> searchResults;
    
    public SearchResult() {
        searched = false;
        searchField = "";
        searchResults = new ArrayList<>();
        outputOrder = new ArrayList<>();
    }
    
    public void setSearchValue(String searchValue) { 
        this.searchField = searchValue;
        this.outputOrder = new ArrayList<>();
        Map<String, String> oO = ServerCache.getCache().getSysConf().getDefaultOutputOrder();
        for(String k : oO.keySet()) {
            if(k.equals(searchValue)) continue;
            OutputOrder order = new OutputOrder(k, oO.get(k));
            outputOrder.add(order);
        }
        setSearched(true);
    }

    public String getSearchField() { return searchField; }
    public boolean isSearched() { return searched; }
    public List<SearchResultElement> getSearchResults() { return searchResults; }
    public List<OutputOrder> getOutputOrder() { return outputOrder; }

    public void setSearched(boolean searched) { this.searched = searched; }
    public void setSearchResults(List<SearchResultElement> searchResults) { this.searchResults = searchResults; }

    public String toString() {
        return searchField + ";" + outputOrder;
    }
}
```

```java
public class SearchResultElement {
    
    private String searchValue;
    private ReferenceSystem refSystem;
    private Map<String,String> valueMap;
    private SystemLocations state;

    public SearchResultElement(String searchValue, ReferenceSystem refSystem, Map<String, String> valueMap) {
        String stateString = getStateString(valueMap);
        this.searchValue = searchValue.toUpperCase();
        this.refSystem = refSystem;
        this.valueMap = valueMap;
        this.state = getState(stateString);
    }

    private String getStateString(Map<String, String> valueMap) {
        for(String key : valueMap.keySet()) {
            if(key.equalsIgnoreCase("STATUS")) {
                String statusString = valueMap.get(key);
                valueMap.remove(key);
                return statusString;
            }
        }
        return "";
    }

    private SystemLocations getState(String state) {
        try {
            SystemLocations sysLoc = SystemLocations.valueOf(state.toUpperCase());
            return sysLoc;
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            if(state.equalsIgnoreCase("NICHT GEFUNDEN")) {
                return SystemLocations.NOTFOUND;
            }
            throw e;
        }
    }

    public String getValue(String fieldName) {
        if("status".equalsIgnoreCase(fieldName)) {
            return state.displayName();
        }
        return valueMap.get(fieldName);
    }

    public boolean isActive() {
        if(state.equals(SystemLocations.PRODUKTIV)) return true;
        return false;
    }
    
    public String getSearchValue() { return searchValue; }
    public String getRefSystem() { return refSystem.displayName(); }
    public ReferenceSystem getReferenceSystem() { return refSystem; }
    public Map<String, String> getValueMap() { return valueMap; }
    public SystemLocations getState() { return state; }

    public void setSearchValue(String searchValue) { this.searchValue = searchValue.toUpperCase(); }
    public void setRefSystem(ReferenceSystem refSystem) { this.refSystem = refSystem; }
    public void setValueMap(Map<String, String> valueMap) { this.valueMap = valueMap; }
    public void setState(SystemLocations state) { this.state = state; }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append(searchValue).append("\n");
        sb.append(refSystem.displayName()).append("\n");
        for(String key : valueMap.keySet()) {
            sb.append(key).append(": ");
            sb.append(valueMap.get(key));
            sb.append("\n");
        }
        sb.append(state.displayName()).append("\n");
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

When I set the class to SessionScope, I get a result which can partly be exported, die fields of the dynamic columns-part stay empty. If I switch to RequestScope all fields stay empty and it looks like there is no searchresult.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: When I change the class to SessionScope, then I get results. But the fields for the dynamic columns stay empty.

Comment: PF version? Can you post a fully reproducible example, reducing your code with only the datatable and mock-up data?

Comment: I've altered my question and added some important classes

Comment: Try to implements Serializable in the bean used within your data table.